# Access device with local ip over internet

Tags: domain-name-system, internet, local, dynamic-dns

I apologize up front if this is the wrong place to post this question. It seemed like the best fit.

I have a device which is connected to my local network which has an IP of 192.168.1.10 from my router.

Additionally I use a Windows 7 machine that runs some software called [DirectUpdate](http://www.directupdate.net/) which allows me to resolve the local IP of the Windows 7 machine (192.168.1.5) to be accessible to the internet via my domain (example.com) - Basic dynamic DNS updating.

I'd like to access the device from example.com. I am unsure how to do this as I don't have any way to install DirectUpdate (or any software) on the device to make the device available to the internet.

Any insight here would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the manufacturer of Direct Update have any documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your definition of "access". I'm going to assume you're talking about a home network with a dynamic IP being assigned by your ISP, and that's what's being resolved by your dynamic DNS updater.

All that DNS does is let you access your public IP address by name -- it does nothing for actually handling access to machines inside your network. Your router is what's directing inbound traffic to your Windows 7 machine to allow you to access it from the internet.

You should be able to configure your router to send traffic for certain set of ports to one device, and for a different set of ports to another. I've used this technique in the past to serve HTTP/HTTPS requests from my always-on microserver while routing SSH traffic to my main system.

Also: this question might be better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) rather than ServerFault.